# Argument labels '(_:)' do not match any available overloads in swift 3.how do fix this?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode8

After updating my code i got stuck with this error.
"Argument labels '(_:)' do not match any available overloads"

```
 var request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: baseURL!)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.httpBody = soapBodyUrlEncoded.data(using:String.Encoding.utf8)
        request.addValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

    let operation = AFHTTPSessionManager(request) //Error in this line
```

Could anyone help me to fix this.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: "i got stuck with this error" - what error?

Comment: `AFHTTPSessionManager` does not have an initialiser accepting `NSMutableURLRequest` as argument. You may init an instance of `AFHTTPSessionManager` and call functions on that.